# Injecting RSpec mocks to avoid allow_any_instance_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I have a Rails project with models `Partner`, `Department`, `Service`.  The partner and department are seeded, the service is created dynamically when `#service` is called on an instance of `Department`.  I'm looking to test the `#ports` functionality of `Service` in request specs.  My first attempt

```rb
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Service).to receive(:ports).and_return(ports)
end

context 'no ports' do
  let(:ports) { [] }
  :
  it 'has status 404' do
    get :show, params: params
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
  end
end
```

Now this works, but I know that `allow_any_instance_of` is a code smell, and one should avoid it if possible.

I tried

```rb
let(:service) { instance_mock(Service) }
let(:department) { Department.find_by( ... ) }
before do
  allow(department).to receive(:service).and_return(service)
  allow(service).to receive(:ports).and_return(ports)
end
```

but that doesn't work, my test `department` is different to the one found in the model (it has a different object_id, I get that).

So I inject as follows

```rb
let(:department) { instance_double(Department) }
let(:service) { instance_double(Service) }
        
before do
  allow(Department).to receive(:find_by).and_return(department)
  allow(department).to receive(:service).and_return(service)
  allow(service).to receive(:ports).and_return(ports)
end
```

Which works as expected. I guess properly this should make some assertions on the arguments to `#find_by`, but even as it stands, it seems a lot more complicated than the "smelly" version, and I'm having difficulty persuading myself that this is better.  One could imagine a situation where there might be a lot of `allow`s needed before you finally get to the object where you can inject your test data.

So my question: is this more-complex style of mock injection worth it to get rid of an `allow_any_instance_of`;  or is there a better way that I've not yet considered?

Comment: i also have the same feeling, a lot of setup to run a test, reducing my enjoy with tdd. temporary i am using [share context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) to setup one time those complex cases and reuse to speed-up a bit.

Comment: That looks about right but you should either add a indirect association (`has_many :ports, through: :service`) or use delegation (`delegate :ports, to: :service`) if it not an association. This will let you simplefy the mocking process by simply calling `allow(department).to receive(:ports).and_return(ports)`. This also removes a Law of Demeter violation which usually is a good thing.